# Magento2 Change Text of Top Links Sign In and Sign Out by Inline Translating

Tags: magento2, inline-translations

I have Installed Latest Magento 2.2.4 version and crate a custom theme,I am doing customization as per our HTML design.Hence I need to change and move top links.I have moved top links successfully but not getting solution to change Sign In and Sign Out text.

I want to change Sign In to Login and Sign Out to Log Out.
    In Magento 1 there was option to change by Inline translation I hope same should work in Magento 2

I have put file en_US.csv

```
 /app/design/frontend/Comapnyname/vendorname/Magento_Customer/i18n/en_US.csv
```

and changed it as per requirement but I am not getting any changed in header links.

Please suggest how I can do that,do I need override any php file or can do this with Inline translate.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already selected your Custom Theme in admin under Content -> Configuration then you can put i18n folder in this location:

```
 /app/design/frontend/Comapnyname/vendorname/i18n/en_US.csv
```

or you can generate this file by using this command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="/full_path_to_this_directory/app/design/frontend/Comapnyname/vendorname/i18n/en_US.csv" /full_path_to_this_directory/app/design/frontend/Comapnyname/vendorname
```

then

Open the newly generated 
`app/design/frontend/Comapnyname/vendorname/i18n/en_US.csv` file and add the following rows:

```
"Sign In", "Login"
```

Now you can run deploy command to get changes of localization,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I tried, its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this by enabling Inline translation from **admin->Advanced->Developer->Translation Inline and changed "Enabled for Storefront" to YES** after I have changed frontend text "Sign In", "Login" as required text.After doing this,translation I have disabled again.

This Solution is great working without coding effort.

Refer image:

[image]